# Is it possible to access RequestScoped class from Singleton class?

Tags: java, singleton, requestscope

I have one Singleton class in my Primefaces Webapp, where I want to query one parameter from my database (for the logged in user). This parameter access function is in other class and this isn't working in my case I already found out where the Exception is thrown (build is wokring fine). This is the call hierarchy, I assume everything else is irrelevant, because elsewhere (singleton is just here) in the app this is working fine:

My Singleton class -> Stateless class -> Other Stateless class -> ApplicationScoped class -> RequestScoped class

The exception comes from the RequestScoped class.

Can someone tell me if this could be usable or the whole concept is bad?

EDIT.:

This is the Exception itself. The main problem is, the here is always the default EntityManager returned, which is not good:

```
public EntityManager get() {
    try {   
        return USED_MANAGERS.get(JSFSessionUtil.getUser());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where "the Exception" is thrown. And what Exception would that be? so far, we see no code, no stacktrace and no configuration. Outside of "have you tried?" what do you want us to answer?

Comment: Edited, but my questions is there. Java class and scope accessibility related.